# Groovy String Concatenation

Tags: string, groovy

Current code:

```
row.column.each(){column ->
    println column.attributes()['name']
    println column.value()
}
```

`Column` is a `Node` that has a single attribute and a single value. I am parsing an xml to input create insert statements into access. Is there a Groovy way to create the following structured statement:

```
Insert INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)
```

I am currently storing the attribute and value to separate arrays then popping them into the correct order.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it can be a lot easier in groovy than the currently accepted answer.  The collect and join methods are built for this kind of thing.  Join automatically takes care of concatenation and also does not put the trailing comma on the string

```
def names = row.column.collect { it.attributes()['name'] }.join(",")
def values = row.column.collect { it.values() }.join(",")
def result = "INSERT INTO tablename($names) VALUES($values)"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Because my setup was table.row.column I used ${table.attributes()['name']} to retrieve the tablename

Answer (score 0):

You could just use two StringBuilders. Something like this, which is rough and untested:

```
def columns = new StringBuilder("Insert INTO tablename(")
def values = new StringBuilder("VALUES (")
row.column.each() { column ->
    columns.append(column.attributes()['name'])
    columns.append(", ")
    values.append(column.value())
    values.append(", ")
}
// chop off the trailing commas, add the closing parens
columns = columns.substring(0, columns.length() - 2)
columns.append(") ")
values = values.substring(0, values.length() - 2)
values.append(")")

columns.append(values)
def result = columns.toString()
```

You can find all sorts of Groovy string manipulation operators [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1525-Strings).

Comment: In Groovy you can append to a StringBuilder using '<<' rather than "append()" which makes the code a lot more readable IMO