# how to get rid of brackets and commas in groovy when printing an array

Tags: java, arrays, json, groovy

I need to print an array without parenthesis

part of a json file

```
 "platforms": [
  {
    "platformCode": "EOS",
    "platformCodeDescription": "Credit Card Servicing  (Voyager) platform"
  },
  {
    "platformCode": "OLB",
    "platformCodeDescription": "Online Retail Bank Servicing Platform"
  }
],
```

part of code

```
def list=json.loginModel.get("platforms")
log.info list
```

output is

```
[{platformCode=EOS, platformCodeDescription=Credit Card Servicing  (Voyager) platform}, {platformCode=OLB, platformCodeDescription=Online Retail Bank Servicing Platform}]
```

if I use this code

```
def list=json.loginModel.get("platforms").platformCode
log.info list
```

output

```
[EOS, OLB]
```

i need the EOS and OLB without `"[]"`and`","`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy String Concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010698/groovy-string-concatenation)

Comment: @cfrick that is different ques.

Comment: the solution is collect and join.  json or sql... whats the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the list of strings

```
['EOS', 'OLB'].join(" ")
===> EOS OLB
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method like this one and pass your list:

```
   public String printArray(String[] platfomrs){
        String result = "";
        for(String code:platfomrs)
            result += result + code + " ";

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log.info json.loginModel.get("platforms").platformCode.get(0)
log.info json.loginModel.get("platforms").platformCode.get(1)
```

will print the desired result

Comment: this is copy and paste code.  at least use a variable. or use a generic approach like `json.loginModel.get("platforms").platformCode.each{ log.info it }`

Comment: @cfrick if any one will read my question carefully he/she can understand this code snippet very easily

Comment: but it will teach them a wrong lesson. first of all, what happens, if you have three or more items in that list? next at least use a variable (`list` in your original example) - [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).